# R: how to visualize data using bwplot()

Tags: r, visualization

```
    library(lattice)
    dd = data.frame(person = c("A", "A", "A", 
                               "B", "B", "B",
                               "C", "C", "C"),
                    score = c("100", "50", "90",
                              "20", "40", "60",
                              "10", "50", "30"),
                    year = c("2001", "2002", "2003",
                             "2001", "2002", "2003",
                             "2001", "2002", "2003"))
    >dd
      person score year
    1      A   100 2001
    2      A    50 2002
    3      A    90 2003
    4      B    20 2001
    5      B    40 2002
    6      B    60 2003
    7      C    10 2001
    8      C    50 2002
    9      C    30 2003
```

I'm interested in seeing how the distribution of the people's scores changed over the years. And I would like to use boxplots to display this information. I would like to use `bwplot()` from the `lattice` library. I am having trouble visualizing and coding...so I know that I would want the scores to be on 1 axis. On the other axis I want the year. So for each year I want to plot distribution of scores from persons A, B, and C. So In total I want to have 3 boxplots, one for the scores in 2001, one for the scores in 2002, and one for the scores in 2003. However, I tried

```
    bwplot(dd$score, groups = dd$year)
```

But that did not work out.

Edit: I tried `bwplot(score ~ year, dd, horiz = F)` but I got this instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean something like

```
dd$score <- as.numeric(as.character(dd$score))
bwplot(score~year, dd, horiz=FALSE)
```

(This assumes `year` is a factor as it is in your sample data. If it's numeric, use `factor(year)`)

Note that most Lattice functions expect a formula as the first parameter, not a simple vector; and typically you use `groups=` for different colors in Lattice while simply supplying a factor variable in the formula will trigger the categorical behavior.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but when I ran the code, I got a different plot. Please refer to my edit.

Comment: @Adrian What version of Lattice does `sessionInfo()` say you are running? Did you redefine `F`? I've updated to explicitly use FALSE.

Comment: @Adrian I just noticed your score values where factors for some reason. Did you pass them in as character for a reason? They seem like numeric values to me. I've converted in my example. Did you test with the sample data you posted?!?

Comment: By the way, do you know how I can rotate the x-axis labels so that they're vertical?

Comment: Try searching for "[r] lattice rotate axis" and see what you come up with.